# Error: Failed to load reCAPTCHA- Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I would appreciate some help to address this error that occurs only on android but no issues with ios.

**intent:**
using firebase phone authentication to send OTP for sign-on

**relevant imports:**

```
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from 'expo-firebase-recaptcha';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../../config';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```

**relevant parts of the code:**

```
const Authentication = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
  const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null);
  const { checkNumber, setPostContactPhone } = useContext(PostContext); // for checking entered number matches previously entered number

  const sendVerification = () => {
    if (checkNumber === phoneNumber) {
      const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
      phoneProvider
        .verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier.current)
        .then(setVerificationId);
      setPhoneNumber('');
    } else {
      Alert.alert(`Phone number does not match. It should be ${checkNumber}`);
    }
  };
  const confirmCode = () => {
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId,
      code
    );
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithCredential(credential)
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert('OTP has been validated!');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
        // alert('Verification code is wrong!!');
      });
  };

  return (
    // ... some elements
          <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
            ref={recaptchaVerifier}
            firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
          />
<Button
              style={styles.sendVerification}
              onPress={sendVerification}
            />
// .... other elements
```

**Problem:**
on pressing button, the reCAPTCHA does not render on the phone and an error ([Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Failed to load reCAPTCHA]) is logged to the console. Only happens with android and no issues with ios.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? Running into the same problem.

Comment: Nope. I ditched this method of validation. Too many moving parts to it.